# tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) not getting called in UITableViewController subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

`numberOfSection` and `numberOfRowsInSection` of `UITableViewController` is getting called but `cellForRow` not. What could be the reason ? Below is the code for `tableViewController`.

```
class GlobalSearchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

/// MARK: Properties

/// Delegate
weak var delegate: GlobalSearchTableViewControllerDelegate?

private var state = GlobalSearchTableState(searchResults: [])

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 60
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

 extension GlobalSearchTableViewController: GlobalSearchTablePresenter {

func present(state: GlobalSearchTableState) {
      tableView.reloadData()

 }
```

Comment: Try without setting "UITableView.automaticDimension".

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Are you sure you've assigned the class from the storyboard?

Comment: set tableview datasource and delegate

Comment: @AashishNagar - how do you know it's not being called? All you are doing is returning an empty cell, so your table view will look empty. Put a `print(indexPath)` statement before `return UITableViewCell()` to confirm whether or not it's being called. I did that with your exact code (removing the undefined `GlobalSearchTableViewControllerDelegate` and `private var state = GlobalSearchTableState(searchResults: [])`), and it calls `cellForRowAt` as expected.

Comment: It got solved. My ViewController view was not being added to its superview.

Answer (score 1):

try to return cell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 var cell : UITableViewCell!
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *tableView.delegate = self* or *tableView.dataSource = self*.